# Can't fix my error. TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Tags: python, typeerror

I am making a game to simulate Roshambo (rock, paper, scissors).
Everything works great, except when you win a game I get an error. Here's my code.

```
###import the random module
import random
import time
##my function
def RockPaperScissors():
    print("This is Roshambo Simulator 2016 copyright © Jared is Cool")
    time.sleep(2.5)
    print("Your score is on the left, and the computers is on the right.")
    time.sleep(1.25)
    score = [0,0]
    print(score)
    cpu  = 1, 2, 3
### game loop! you choose your weapon
    while True:
        while True:
            choice = input("Rock(1), Paper(2), or Scissors(3)?")
            if choice == "1":
                whichOne  = 1
                break
            elif choice == "2":
                whichOne =  2
                break
            elif choice == "3":
                whichOne =  3
                break

##who wins the roshambo
        cpu = random.choice(cpu)
        if whichOne == cpu:
            print("stale!")
            print(score)
        elif (whichOne == 3 and cpu == 2) or (whichOne == 2 and cpu == 1) or (whichOne == 1 and cpu == 3):
            print("win!")
            score[0] = score[0] + 1
            print(score)
        else:
            print("lose")
            print(score)
            score[1] = score[1] + 1

RockPaperScissors()
```

Here is the error I keep getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 41, in <module>
  File "python", line 28, in RockPaperScissors
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: ``cpu = random.choice(cpu)`` here you replace your list of choices by the choice (an integer). Try `cpu_choice = random.choice(cpu)` and replace the following `cpu`-names. :)

Comment: `cpu = random.choice(cpu)` is replacing your tuple `1, 2, 3` with a single choice. The second time through the loop you get the error you report. A good debugging technique is to put `print` statements before the line that gives an error to check that your variables contain what you expect.

Comment: Thanks MSeifert for the help, and thanks Paul Hankin for the advice. This fixed my problem. Good job!

Comment: I've also written an answer. Took me a bit because I've also commented on other parts of your code. But these are optional I'm glad it works!

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is on this line:

```
cpu = random.choice(cpu)
```

The first time that runs, it works because `cpu` is assigned a tuple at the start of your code. It fails when the loop comes around again though, since you've replaced the tuple with a single value (an integer).

I suggest using a different variable for one value, so the line would be something like:

```
cpu_choice = random.choice(cpu)
```

You could alternatively use `random.randint(1,3)` to pick the value and not bother with the tuple at all.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments:

> `cpu = random.choice(cpu)` here you replace your list of choices by the choice (an integer). Try `cpu_choice = random.choice(cpu)` and replace the following `cpu`-names.

But you can also do some more stuff to make it shorter:

## The player choice:

```
while True:
    choice = input("Rock(1), Paper(2), or Scissors(3)?")
    if choice in ["1", "2", "3"]:
        whichOne = int(choice)
        break
```

## Computer choice:

```
cpu_choice = random.choice(cpu)

if whichOne == cpu_choice:
    print("stale!")

elif (whichOne, cpu_choice) in [(3, 2), (2, 1), (1, 3)]:
    print("win!")
    score[0] = score[0] + 1

else:
    print("lose")
    score[1] = score[1] + 1

print(score) # Call it after the if, elif, else
```